# Angular 2+: change attribute with onclick

Tags: angular

I have a button with the attribute mat-raised-button

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="function()">My Button</button>
```

I would like to add or remove the mat-raised-button attribute with my function.
Is there a way to do this? Or will I need to change the CSS instead?

Comment: Is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/angular-4-how-to-apply-a-directive-conditionally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using only 1 button.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" [attr.mat-raised-button]="attributeCondition ? '': null" (click)="changeAttributeCondition()">Button</button>
```

- Setting attribute as a null will remove that
- Setting attribute with blank, just add that attribute
- Setting attribute with any value, set attribute

For ref: [Discussion over here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2869#issuecomment-123032491)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different buttons and using ***ngIf** you can display only one at a time based on your condition.

```
<button mat-button (click)="function()" *ngIf="!isCondition">My Button</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="function()" *ngIf="isCondition">My Button</button>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect, this works great, I should have thought about it earlier ^^'