# How can we apply custom directive conditionally in angular 6 when using node projection with <ng-container></ng-container>?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to apply custom directive based on some condition in angular reactive form.But I have not find any way to implement this feature.
Structural directive is not working in node projection.

```
     <input
        type="text"
        *customDirective="data"
       // directive1 /directive2    
       // I have to apply above directive based on some condition      
         />
```

Comment: What do you mean by conditional component? Can you please just explain what is your requirement?

Comment: Please add the corresponding code to the question to make a working example of what you have, this helps the SO community to better answer your question [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a directive conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally)

Comment: Please show your usage of your custom directive

Comment: Will it be like this `<p appBasicHighlight></p>` or  `<p *appBasicHighlight="'red'"></p>`

Comment: @ dileepkumar jami  It will be like <p *appBasicHighlight="'red'"></p>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[customRequired]'
})
export class CustomRequired {
    @Input() customRequired: boolean;

    @HostListener('change', ['$event'])
    onCall(event) {
        if(this.customRequired) {
        // code to be done ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use structural directive in node projection. Its not working in node projection