# Is there any way to add or remove directive using condition in angular framework?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am using directive selector on click event which give asc and desc but i want to remove this directive while my reactive form is dirty. appSortable is directive selector

```
<div class="bank-name sort" appSortable sortDirection="asc" (sorted)="onSortedBankName($event)" (click)="sortColumnBy(bankConstants.sortBy.name)"  #Sortable>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a directive conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally)

Answer (score 2):

Why not using *ngIf in your template?

```
<div *ngIf="myForm.dirty" class="bank-name sort">
<div *ngIf="!myForm.dirty" class="bank-name sort" appSortable sortDirection="asc" (sorted)="onSortedBankName($event)" (click)="sortColumnBy(bankConstants.sortBy.name)"  #Sortable>
```

Comment: in click event i need to check form is dirty or not then warning model will pupup what if user Click 'YES" how to store previous   sortDirection = (asc or desc)  and sortBy

Answer (score 0):

Can you not update your directive to accept an enabled property and then set it to the state of the form?

```
[isEnabled]="!myForm.dirty"
```

Have your directive do nothing if this value is false.

Answer (score 0):

Having two similar codes is fine only if the code is 1-liner. If it spans multiple rows, the code can get too ugly too soon.

You can have an input parameter to your directive. You can pass the value of `form.dirty` to the directive and apply whatever logic you want there. It also saves you from duplicating the code.

See example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-directive)

Edit: Made the solution more generic, Each component can have its own function and sort accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to hide your content if form is dirty

```
<div *ngIf="!YourFormName.dirty" class="bank-name sort" appSortable sortDirection="asc" (sorted)="onSortedBankName($event)" (click)="sortColumnBy(bankConstants.sortBy.name)"  #Sortable>
```