# Angular 4 add directive on same tag conditionally

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, angular-ng-if

I'm using angular 4 and I have a directive that I need to add on my template to validate some stuff. But i want to first evaluate if another condition is true then apply the directive. Right now my code is like this:

```
<div *ngIf="groupCheck; else NoDirective" #Directive>
 <li [directive]="controlGroup"><a [routerLink]="['/account/search/', '']"
                    routerLinkActive="active">Accounts</a></li>
 <li [directive]="controlGroup"><a [routerLink]="['/orders', '']"
                    routerLinkActive="active">Orders</a></li>
 <li [directive]="DIFFERENT_GROUP"><a [routerLink]="['/report']" routerLinkActive="active">Reports</a>
                </li>
 <li [directive]="controlGroup"><a [routerLink]="['/anotherStuff']" routerLinkActive="active">anotherStuff</a></li>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!groupCheck; else Directive" #NoDirective>
 <li><a [routerLink]="['/account/search/', '']" routerLinkActive="active">Accounts</a></li>
 <li><a [routerLink]="['/orders', '']" routerLinkActive="active">Orders</a></li>
 <li><a [routerLink]="['/report']" routerLinkActive="active">Reports</a></li>
 <li><a [routerLink]="['/anotherStuff']" routerLinkActive="active">anotherStuff</a></li>
</div>
```

I want to find a way to do something like this:

```
<li *NgIf="condition true add [directive]=controlGroup; else Don't add directive to this line/tag/element"><a [routerLink]="['/account/search/', '']"
                    routerLinkActive="active">Accounts</a></li>
 <li *NgIf="condition true add [directive]=controlGroup; else Don't add directive to this line/tag/element"><a [routerLink]="['/orders', '']"
                    routerLinkActive="active">Orders</a></li>
 <li *NgIf="condition true add [directive]=DIFFERENTGROUP; else Don't add directive to this line/tag/element"><a [routerLink]="['/report']" routerLinkActive="active">Reports</a>
                </li>
 <li *NgIf="condition true add [directive]=controlGroup; else Don't add directive to this line/tag/element"><a [routerLink]="['/anotherStuff']" routerLinkActive="active">anotherStuff</a></li>
```

So that way I won't have to rewrite the whole code for just one condition and won't need the conditional div. Is there a way to do this?

-----******UPDATE******-----
@Allabakash guided me with a possible solution from a post:

```
<button [attr.md-raised-button]="condition ? '' : null"></button>
```

My problem now is that my directive (which I can't access) eliminates the whole element if it gets null or a name that doesn't appear in the method. Here's how it works:

```
set checkGroup(hasGroups: string) {
    if (hasGroups) {
      this.AuthService.hasOtherGroups(hasGroups, false).subscribe(res => {
        if (!res) {
          this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement);
        } else {
          this.el.nativeElement.style.display = '';
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement);
    }
  }
```

Which leaves me with the big q: is there a way that I can use this directive with a condition inside the

that makes me apply the directive on the element, and if the result is null do not let the directive apply so I can avoid repeating the whole menu?

Thanks for your time :).

Comment: you can look into this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally/46912525#46912525

Comment: Kind of what I'm looking, thanks. The problem is the freaking directive that I need to use. If i pass a null value, it removes the whole element. That's how the directive works and I can't change it. I'll update the question with how the directive works.

Answer (score 2):

2 possibilities:

- You can put your condition in your directive (to pass data to your directive)
- Create two elements with ngIf:

  `<div *ngIf="false"></div>
   <div *ngIf="true" myDirective></div>`

Comment: that's what I did, the question was if i could validate in one line and if the condition was false then do not use the directive, the solution that you propose makes me write two times the code :(.

Comment: Yes I think it's better to put logic into the directive

Answer (score 0):

Create your [custom structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives), pass your params into it and perform any logic you want to inside... I.e...

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myDirective]' })
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
    private _config;

    @Input()
    set myDirective(config) {
        this._config = config
    }

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this._config) {
            this.viewContainer.clear()
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Its just an example, but you can perform any action based on any events,:, ie Input change. observable emit, etc...

Apply structural directive the same way ngIf applied...

```
<ng-container *myDirective="config"></ng-container>
```

Comment: you mean that I have to create and use another directive and not use the [directive] that is already made? Cause if this is the case I can't use it. I have to use the [directive] that has been created (Company terms yei #not).

So the question is basically: can I use some condition to that LI that validates if the Company Directive  returns null but avoiding the removeChild that causes if the element to be removed without change the Company Directive?

The idea is make less code with this idea, if there's no way possible, then I'll leave it that way.