# How to wrap a element by different div conditionally in Angular

Tags: angular

Lets say I have a element tree and I want to wrap it in different div based on a condition
eg.

```
//condition == 1
<div class="condition1" condition1Directive>
   <div> ... </div>   //same content
</div>

//condition == 2
<div class="condition2">
   <div> ... </div>   //same content
</div>
```

I would like to find the most elegant and efficient way to do this in angular.
Thanks

Comment: Is the just the class attribute changing for the wrapping div or it could be any other element?

Comment: No. I have updated my question. I want to have some directives in particular div.

Comment: Are you talking about using one directive if `condition1` and the other directive if `condition2`? Slightly confused about your end goal. I think `*ngIf` is what you want, but I don't quite know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My actual case is using directive in condition1 and no directive in condition2

Comment: It is an interesting question. Can you please explain in detail, what are the two conditions ? Why only through directive ? What is your end exact result ?

Comment: Actually I have a view that will be presented in mobile and desktop. In desktop I would like it can be drag and drop so I use angular drag and drop and it requires directive. While in mobile, I don't support the drag and drop. This is the real case I am facing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to just enclose divs with different styling properties you can use ngClass

```
<div [ngClass]="{'condition1': condition === 1, 'condition2': condition === 2}"> 


<div> ... </div>   //same content

</div>
```

For using conditional directive you can do something like this:

```
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="condition1 === true ? template1 : template2">

<ng-template #template1 directive> <ng-template>

<ng-template #template2></ng-template>
```

Comment: sorry that I should be more clear on my question. I have updated it and actually I want to have some directives in particular div.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do like this ways ..**

**CASE 1**

```
<div *ngIf="condition1" class="condition1" condition1Directive>
   <div> ... </div>   //same content
</div>

<div *ngIf="condition2" class="condition2">
   <div> ... </div>   //same content
</div>
```

**CASE 2**

```
<div [ngClass]="condition1 == true ? 'condition1' : 'condition2'" condition1Directive>
   <div> ... </div>   //same content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *ngIf for the parent div, extract the same content div to a ng-template or component if necessary.

You can check this thread for more detail:

[Apply a directive conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally)

```
<div *ngIf="isCondition1" condition1Directive>
  <sameContentComponent></sameContentComponent>
</ng-container>

<div *ngIf="!isCondition1">
  <sameContentComponent></sameContentComponent>
</ng-container>
```