# How to apply a conditional based Custom Directive based on property value in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular9, angular-pipe, angular10

I have two directives, one directive accepts a nonnegative number and the other accepts only positive numbers based on some types.

In HTMLtemplate how can do the conditional statement?

```
  <input *ngIf="productType ==='Amazon' ? OnlyNumber="true" : NegativeNumber" type="text" formControlName="price">
```

two directives below

OnlyNumber="true" directive for positive
NegativeNumber: directive for negative

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply a directive conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally)

Comment: @that is one directive with some condition but in my case two directives , i have check some property value if true assign one directive else another directive.

Comment: You could do add each directive in the corresponding condition: `<input *ngIf="productType==='Amazon'" OnlyNumber='true'><input *ngIf="productType!='Amazon'" NegativeNumber>`.  Only either of the element will be rendered since the conditions are contradictory.

Comment: oh ok let me try this.. is it able to do with single input field `*ngIf="productType==='Amazon'" ? directiveone : directivetwo'"`

Comment: It won't be possible. The condition will try to evaluate `directiveone` and `directivetwo` as variable names instead of directive selectors.

Comment: @thanks for the valuable comments. it works..