# Optional MatDatePicker on MatInput

Tags: html, angular, binding, datepicker, attributes

Since my text and date inputs on an Angular form (built with `*ngFor`) have all the same styling (except for the type of input, of course), I want to combine them to make them easier to maintain. So I have done the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let form of source">
  <div [ngSwitch]="form.type">
    <mat-form-field *ngSwitchDefault>
      <mat-label>{{form.displayName}}</mat-label>
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="form.format">
        <input *ngSwitchDefault matInput formControlName="{{form.displayName}}" otherAttributes
               [attr.matDatepicker]="form.type === 'date' ? 'picker' : null">
      </ng-container>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle *ngIf="form.type === 'date'" matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

I originally tried this without the `attr.` on the `matDatepicker` in the `input`, but then the compiler complains that `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'MatDatepickerPanel<MatDatepickerControl<any>, any, any>'.` Using attribute binding is supposed to drop the attribute altogether when it evaluates to `null` or `undefined`, but when I do it this way, it compiles fine but the browser fails with `Attempted to open an [sic] MatDatepicker with no associated input` when I click the datepicker toggle, so it would seem it fails to set the attribute in either case. I get this result whether I have quotes around `picker` in the expression or not, since the rules for attribute binding specify that it should evaluate to a string.

Does this mean that attribute binding won't work for this situation? What else might I be doing wrong here? Is there some other trick I can use to base the text and date inputs on the same definition, or am I going to have to write and maintain almost identical definitions for these two controls?

Edit: Oh, and if I don't make it optional, then it forces all my non-date inputs to only take date inputs.

Answer (score -1):

> Does this mean that attribute binding won't work for this situation?

I am sorry to say that, but: Yes, this won´t work.

That is because you apply a value to an attribute but you don´t actually create the directive. (Compare: [Apply a directive conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally))

So unfortunatly you can´t use a single input for what you want to achieve. At least you only need a single mat-form-field. (Small hint: The closing tag is missing)

Comment: Ah, the missing closing tag, the joys of copying code by hand never cease. I also forgot the closing `>` on the `input`; I've fixed both now. Unfortunately, other switch cases aren't compatible with `mat-form-field`, so I get the choice to either make yet another switch statement inside the `mat-form-field`, or multiple `mat-form-field`s. I choose the latter.

Comment: Well, making multiple `mat-form-field` makes no sense I think. Remove the `ngSwitch` from the div and move it to `mat-form-field`. Make standard text input your default and an `ng-container` (which includes another input + datepicker components) for date types.

Comment: Again, there are other switch cases not shown which are not compatible with `mat-form-field`. For example, radio buttons are not compatible with `mat-form-field`, so either I nested `switch` the same value twice, or I make multiple `mat-form-field`s. Of the two, nesting the same `switch` feels more "wrong" to me, but I suppose that's a personal preference, Either way, I duplicate some work somewhere.

Comment: As I look at it, I almost agree with you, but the switch statements start to look like spaghetti if I do it, which almost defeats the purpose of making it more readable and maintainable. My original idea would have simplified some of the mess, but I think it's at right at the point where doing it halfway is worse than not doing it at all, especially since I had already made the duplicate `mat-form-field` that I was hoping to simplify away.