# How to add cdkDrag conditionally in Angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I want to add `cdkDrag` conditionally. I tried the following ways but none of them does not work.

```
public canDragAndDrop:boolean=true ; // false

<div [attr.cdkDrag]="canDragAndDrop ? '':null"></div>
// or
<div [attr.cdkDrag]="canDragAndDrop ? 'cdkdrag':null"></div>
// or  
<div cdkDrag="{{canDragAndDrop ? '':null}}"></div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply a directive conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally)

Comment: I tried all of them but does not work for `cdkDrag`

Comment: The link provided are all the answer wrong. a directive is **not** an attribute. A directive change the tag and make a "super tag". I suggest use cdkDragDisabled: `[cdkDragDisabled]="!canDragAndDrop "` or use two divs, one with the cdkDrag and another one without cdkDrag and use a *ngIf to show only one div at time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that conditionally binding a directive is possible, however, I managed to achieve what I wanted as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="draggable">
  <div cdkDrag cdkDragHandle cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane"
       [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition" (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event)">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="header"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!draggable">
  <div>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="header"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```