# Angular JS - adding a custom directive to an element with ng-switch-when directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-switch, angularjs-ng-switch

Using AngularJS 1.5, I've built a custom attribute directive, that adds a date-range-picker directive, and it's options, to the element :

```
app.directive('clSingleDatePicker', function($compile) {
    var opts_single_date = {
        singleDatePicker: true
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
            element.attr('date-range-picker', '');
            element.attr('options', 'opts');
            element.removeAttr("cl-single-date-picker"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    scope.opts = opts_single_date;
                    $compile(iElement)(scope);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

When I'm adding this directive to a simple input like this:

```
<input cl-single-date-picker type="text" ng-model="someModel"/>
```

I'll get the required result in the DOM:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someModel" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-touched" date-range-picker="" options="opts" style="">
```

And the date-range-picker is active and doing it's work. 
However, If I'm adding a conditional directive to my element, In my case ng-switch-when:

```
<input  ng-switch-when="1" cl-single-date-picker type="text" ng-model="someModel"/>
```

This element will not be rendered at all, even though, the directive function is being executed. How can I add my directive to an element with a conditional directive on it and have it rendered?

**A working solution (Edited)**
By adding a priority value higher than the ng-switch (which is 1200 [apparently](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)), The customed directive is now being executed before the ng-switch-then directive, and the datepicker is being rendered.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566118/angular-js-ng-switch-when-not-working-with-dynamic-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: misunderstood the question**

It looks like the `ng-switch-when` is also being applied to the attribute directive, but it either thinks it's not within an `ng-switch` or it does not have access to the outer scope, so the `ng-switch-when` resolves to `false`.

There are a couple of solutions:

1) Wrap the `input` in a `span` and put the `ng-switch-when` on that instead of the `input`

2) Remove the `ng-switch-when` attribute in the directive `element.removeAttr("ng-switch-when");`

Both seem to work (when experimenting in a Plunker).  Personally, I prefer the first as it's all within the template.

---

### Original answer:

`ng-switch` affects the element it is on, not the attributes within it. There are a few ways of conditionally showing the custom attribute:

If you wanted to use `ng-switch`, you could have two inputs:

```
<input ng-switch-when="1" cl-single-date-picker type="text" ng-model="someModel"/>
<input ng-switch-when="2" type="text" ng-model="someModel"/>
```

Alternatively, you could [add an extra attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16549432/4166407) on your directive and do the check in the directive, e.g.

```
<input cl-single-date-picker show-picker="{{showPicker}}" type="text" ng-model="someModel"/>
```

You may also be able to use [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes) to conditionally apply the attribute (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26148139/4166407)).  I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Thanx, Sophie, but this is not what I've meant - my problem is that when the element has the ng-switch-when combined with my directive, it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I misunderstood the question!

Comment: A slightly hacky solution (but possibly the simplest) could be to wrap the input in a `span` and put the `ng-switch-when` on that instead of the input.

Comment: @AgentZmith I've edited my answer. Hope that's more helpful!

Comment: Yes @Sophie, that's probably the solution I'll adopt (option 1), thanks.

Comment: @AgentZmith Could you mark it as correct if it works please? :)